# How to create a counter to see how many times a website has been accessed? (Not unique. Total)

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to research if there is a way to check whether or not the web page has been accessed.  All I'm trying to do is display how many times the website has been accessed by creating a simple counter with a variable and add to that variable with the check condition.  I'm wondering if there is a way to check for this condition within javascript?

Comment: No, it is not possible. JavaScript is just a code which is executed independently on every client. You will need an application (server) with any sort of storage (file, database etc.) to do this.

Comment: You need serverside code for this...

Comment: Pure JS, not possible, JS+Backend Possible!

Comment: You need some kind of a storage to store the count, so that you can increment it with every new visit. It could be a database, a file, or you could find a free API on the internet that would do the counting for you.

Comment: It's a server side job. also you can use google analytics

Comment: Just did the researching for you and found a free API tool that stores your count: https://count.io/ The rest is a matter of an AJAX call to get the count and another one to increment it.